# INR sign ₹ is missing in the Jobs Match Preferences section

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

In the **Jobs -> Match Preferences -> Minimum annual compensation** section the salary currency dropdownlist having country wise currency along with it's sign.

[Indian rupee sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rupee_sign) is missing from this list. After inspect the dropdownlist element I see the **option** is not having the INR sign `₹` in it.

```
<option value="INR">Indian Rupees ()</option>
```

Filling the `₹` in the **option** will work fine.

```
<option value="INR">Indian Rupees (₹)</option>
```

[image: INR sign missing in the list]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

The symbol is now displayed: `Indian rupees (₹)`.

**Initial answer:**

`(INR)` will be shown instead of `()` in the next build (build rev `2016.5.25.4556` on MSE/MSO, `2016.5.25.3612` on sites), fixing the immediate bug.

We'll evaluate adding the symbol to our currencies table in careers, though.

Comment: Verified `(INR)` replaced `()`. Eagerly waiting to see the `₹` symbol instead of `(INR)`

Comment: Verified, `₹` added in the [dropdownlist](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tqV9t.png). Thanks.